# Iteratively select rows in Pandas dataframes to form single df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict of dataframes:

```
data1 = {'A': [1, 2, 3],
         'B': [4, 5, 6],
         'my_value': [0.1, 0.4, 0.3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# Example DataFrame 2
data2 = {'A': [7, 8, 9],
         'B': [10, 11, 12],
         'my_value': [0.2, 0.5, 0.6]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Example DataFrame 3
data3 = {'A': [13, 14, 15],
         'B': [16, 17, 18],
         'my_value': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)

dfs = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'df3': df3}
```

In the above dataframes, the order counts. I would like to obtain a new, single dataframe by iteratively selecting the first rows of each df, then the second rows, then the third etc. Each of these selections should be then sorted by 'my_value', and concatenated together in a single df.

Basically, starting from the above example, the first three rows of the outcome should be the first rows of each dataset, sorted by 'my_value'; then the seconds, and the thirds in the same fashion.

Comment: What you exactly want is not fully clear. Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dataframes have the same index, you can just sort the concatenation:

```
(pd.concat(dfs).rename_axis(index=['data','idx'])
   .sort_values(['idx','my_value'])
)
```

Output:

```
           A   B  my_value
data idx                  
df1  0     1   4       0.1
df2  0     7  10       0.2
df3  0    13  16       0.9
df1  1     2   5       0.4
df2  1     8  11       0.5
df3  1    14  17       0.8
df1  2     3   6       0.3
df2  2     9  12       0.6
df3  2    15  18       0.7
```

Comment: thanks! i'll accept your reply since it's very similar to what I came up with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a double `groupby`:

```
tmp = pd.concat(dfs).sort_values(by='my_value')

out = [g for _, g in tmp.groupby(tmp.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), sort=False)]
```

Output:

```
[        A   B  my_value
df1 0   1   4       0.1
df2 0   7  10       0.2
df3 2  15  18       0.7,

         A   B  my_value
df1 2   3   6       0.3
df2 1   8  11       0.5
df3 1  14  17       0.8,

         A   B  my_value
df1 1   2   5       0.4
df2 2   9  12       0.6
df3 0  13  16       0.9]
```

Variant, if you want to subset by N rows:

```
N = 2

tmp = pd.concat(dfs).sort_values(by='my_value')

out = [g for _, g in tmp.groupby(tmp.groupby(level=0).cumcount()//N, sort=False)]
```

Output:

```
[        A   B  my_value  # first N rows
df1 0   1   4       0.1
df2 0   7  10       0.2
df1 2   3   6       0.3
df2 1   8  11       0.5
df3 2  15  18       0.7
    1  14  17       0.8,

         A   B  my_value  # next N rows
df1 1   2   5       0.4
df2 2   9  12       0.6
df3 0  13  16       0.9]
```

Sorting by value and rows number:

```
pd.concat(dfs).sort_values(by='my_value').assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).sort_values(by='n')
```

Output:

```
        A   B  my_value  n
df1 0   1   4       0.1  0
df2 0   7  10       0.2  0
df3 2  15  18       0.7  0
df1 2   3   6       0.3  1
df2 1   8  11       0.5  1
df3 1  14  17       0.8  1
df1 1   2   5       0.4  2
df2 2   9  12       0.6  2
df3 0  13  16       0.9  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone suggesting a solution! I immediately realised that it was easier than I thought. It was enough to add a further column with the rank in the df, let's call it `position`

```
for k,v in dfs.items():
    v['position'] = [x for x in range(1, len(v)+1)]
```

and then simply:

```
pd.concat(dfs).reset_index().groupby('position', group_keys=False)
.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('my_value', ascending=False))
```

in a very similar fashion to what was suggested in the second answer to my question.